# Can the ImageResizer DLL accommodate Scalable Vector Graphics (.SVG) images

Tags: imageresizer

I am using creative version of image-resizer.

Can the Image-Resizer DLL accommodate Scalable Vector Graphics (.SVG) images

I have found this

[image: Imageformat]

Thanks

Comment: That's something you should ask the author of that library. From the documentation I'd say, no, SVG isn't supported. That being said, you can just embed SVG images with a different size. They scale well, hence the name.

Answer (score 1):

ImageResizer doesn't rasterize SVG images into bitmaps, although one of our customers (@adamdbradley) has made an ImageResizer plugin for it that does just that.

You may consider using the SVG directly, as SVGs are inherently scalable and browser support is pretty good in 2014.

Alternatively, you could shell out to Inkscape for the render stage.